# SQL Join tables and get rows that don't match with NULL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm working with Microsoft SQL Server. I've tried to find something similar but I don't understand how to adapt it to my code so I would be grateful for your help with some code samples.

Table 1 - 'EMER'

```
Patient             AdDate             AdNum              MedRec   
-----------------------------------------------------------------
A                 2022-06-17            4356             5456744
B                 2022-06-17            2345             5423908
C                 2022-06-17            3324             5421763
```

Table 2 - 'DESCRIP'

```
Patient            MedRec         NurseAssesment
------------------------------------------------------
A                 5456744         text text text
C                 5421763         text text text
```

what I want a joined table including rows that don't match

how can I do it if 'B' doesn't exist at all at table 2?

patient B has not seen a nurse so he doesn't exist on table 2, not even NULL value. I want the option to show that he hasn't seen the nurse hence to give him a NULL value.

Table 3 -

```
Patient             AdDate             AdNum              MedRec        NurseAssesment     
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
A                 2022-06-17            4356             5456744        text text text
B                 2022-06-17            2345             5423908        NULL
C                 2022-06-17            3324             5421763        text text text
```

Second question: after I created the joined table above (Table 3), how can I add a column of binary option if the patient has NULL value in 'NurseAssesment' so give him 0, else 1:

Table 4 -

```
Patient             AdDate             AdNum              MedRec        NurseAssesment         HasSeenNurse     
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
A                 2022-06-17            4356             5456744        text text text              1
B                 2022-06-17            2345             5423908        NULL                        0
C                 2022-06-17            3324             5421763        text text text              1
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between "INNER JOIN" and "OUTER JOIN"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38549/what-is-the-difference-between-inner-join-and-outer-join)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want to use `LEFT JOIN` between `EMER` table and `DESCRIP` table, while keeping the left side in case you do not have any records in the right, by matching the `MedRec` records.

```
SELECT e.*,
d.NurseAssesment,
CASE WHEN NurseAssesment IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS HasSeenNurse
FROM EMER e
LEFT JOIN DESCRIP d
ON e.MedRec = d.MedRec
```